# 'function' object has no attribute 'str' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using below code to read and split the csv file strings separated by /

```
DATA IS 
SRC_PATH                        TGT_PATH
/users/sn/Retail                /users/am/am
/users/sn/Retail Reports/abc    /users/am/am
/users/sn/Automation            /users/am/am
/users/sn/Nidh                  /users/am/xzy
```

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('E:\RCTemplate.csv',index_col=None, header=0)
s1 = df.SRC_PATH.str.split('/', expand=True)
```

i get the correct split data in s1, but when i am going to do the similar operation on single row it throws error "'function' object has no attribute 'str'"

error is throwing in below code

```
df2= [(df.SRC_PATH.iloc[0])]
df4=pd.DataFrame([(df.SRC_PATH.iloc[0])],columns = ['first'])
newvar = df4.first.str.split('/', expand=True)
```

Comment: Pandas thinks you are trying to access the method [dataframe.first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas thinks you are trying to access the method [dataframe.first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html).

This is why it's best practice to use hard brackets to access dataframe columns rather than `.column` access

`df4['first'].str.split()` instead of `df4.first.str.split()`

Not that this cause common issues with things like a column called `'name'` ending up as the `name` attribute of the dataframe and a host of other problems

Comment: thank you @G.Anderson it worked. i will surely keep in mind. i would like to know why it didnt throw error at s1 ??

Comment: Because `.` columns access _is_ valid python, and dataframes don't have a method or attribute `.SRC_PATH()`. The issue is that your column name `'first'`, shadows the built-in `.first` method

Comment: THank u. i will dip dive to avoid these.